# Does Visual Studio let you set the scrollbar's 'deleted foreground' color?

Tags: visual-studio, customization

In VS Code, I can change the color of deleted lines as highlighted in the scrollbar with the `editorOverviewRuler.deletedForeground` setting.  I don't like it being red as that's too close to the "error" highlight.  Is there an equivalent for Visual Studio?

*Note: I've discovered that you can get rid of the change colouring entirely by going into `Text Editor | All Languages | Scroll Bars` and unchecking "Show changes", which is better than nothing.  Still, being able to change the color would be nicer.*